# Should 'site default' be an option in a select list?

Tags: pagination, settings, profile

An example: a user can choose the number of items per page when pagination is used. The choices could be predefined or free to choose.

Should I provide an option like 'site default (10)', noting that the value could change in the future?

I may not have picked the best example for this, but it should get the idea across.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a user, is there any benefit in knowing the default value? For pagination, probably not. For some other cases, probably yes.

Anyway, *if* you want to note which value is the default one, you should change the order of your example, so that each value keeps in line:

> - 5
> - 10 (default)
> - 15

instead of

> - 5
> - default (10)
> - 15

"Site" could be omitted, I guess, as it doesn’t add any useful information.

Answer (score 3):

Having a choice of 'Default' sounds like a good idea to me.  I think that the 'follow the default' selection should be separate from the other 'fixed' selections that you provide like so:

- Default (5)
- 5
- 10
- 15

That way its clear that you can pick '5' or 'the default'.  Having it look slightly different is ok since it means something slightly different than the other selections.

Comment: This option has the advantage of being able to say "I want it to be 5, and if the default changes, I still want it to be 5."